# jQuery. Replacing text in a table is unformatting the entire table

Tags: jquery, text

I'm using jQuery to replace two words "Final Cost" in a table and replace them with "Current Projected Cost". I've gotten the code to change the words but it takes away the formatting. (removes dynamically created bold (strong) and line returns - br/).

Here is the current code:

```
 $("document").ready(function(){

    $(".current-projects td:contains(Final Cost:)").text(function (i, old) {
 return old
      .replace('Final Cost', 'Current Projected Cost');

    });
});
```

Here is a link to see issue:
http://www.lampinc.net/projects/current-projects/cgh-medical-center-emergency-department-expansion-and-renovation/

How do I help to preserve the formatting? Thanks.

Comment: Use `.html()` instead of `.text()`.

Comment: What about using regex to replace the text in the table cells?

Comment: @Terry If you only operate on the text, you'll lose all the HTML markup, just like his original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.html()` to keep all the markup:

```
$(".current-projects td:contains(Final Cost:)").html(function (i, old) {
    return old.replace('Final Cost', 'Current Projected Cost');

});
```